# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($var) must be of type Countable|array, null given in

Tags: php, count

The code was working perfectly until when I installed **XAMPP 8 (PHP 8)**.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    @$subject = $_POST['subject'];
    @$term = $_POST['term'];
    @$session = $_POST['session'];
    @$size = count($_POST['adm_num']);
    @$size = count($_POST['ca1']);
    @$size = count($_POST['ca2']);
    @$size = count($_POST['ca3']);

    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $size) {
        $ca1= $_POST['ca1'][$i];
        $ca2= $_POST['ca2'][$i];
        $ca3= $_POST['ca3'][$i];
        $adm_num = $_POST['adm_num'][$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using `count()` on non-array.

Comment: Avoid the use of the `@` operator. Check with `isset()` or `empty()`.

Comment: Side note: what is the point in defining `$size` and then overwriting it three times?

Comment: @El_Vanja I guess when one of the post parameters is missing, the subsequent one will define the value of $size.

Answer (score 59):

You must defined variable with array() before use it.
or

```
if (is_countable($aa) && count($aa) > 0) :
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `is_countable`, definitely the most direct solution here!

Answer (score 24):

On **PHP8.0** compulsory types are define on Count.

```
count((array)$XYZVariable);
```

**try This Code**

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    @$subject = $_POST['subject'];
    @$term = $_POST['term'];
    @$session = $_POST['session'];
    @$size = count((array)$_POST['adm_num']));
    @$size = count((array)$_POST['ca1']));
    @$size = count((array)$_POST['ca2']));
    @$size = count((array)$_POST['ca3']));

    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $size) {
        $ca1= $_POST['ca1'][$i];
        $ca2= $_POST['ca2'][$i];
        $ca3= $_POST['ca3'][$i];
        $adm_num = $_POST['adm_num'][$i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Easy Fix ..

```
$ab = is_array($aa) ? count($aa) : 0 ;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
@$size = count($_POST['ca1']);
```

in PHP 8 will not work you have to do it like that

```
@$size = count((array)$_POST['ca1']);
```

and do this for the rest of it

Comment: Downvoted because of the @
Bad practice to suppress errors with that!

Comment: In PHP 8.0+ `@` operators work [differently](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/fatal-error-suppression#:~:text=PHP%20supports%20the%20%40%20error%20control,operator%20can%20suppress%20these%20errors.). Calling it "bad practice" is now more a matter of opinion or for OGs who can't deny the fact that the use cases are actually on point now.

Answer (score 7):

For easier code update for PHP8 I made my own function

```
function count_($array) {
    return is_array($array) ? count($array) : 0;
}
```

and then I mass replaced count($value) with count_($value)

Comment: Be careful with this solution. In my project there are custom count methods like `$UsersModel->count()` which will absolutely cause problems

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the official php docs for [count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php):

> Counts all elements in an array, or something in an object.

The error you're getting is pretty obvious. One of these four variables(`$_POST['adm_num']`, `$_POST['ca1']`, `$_POST['ca2']`, `$_POST['ca3']`) is not an array or maybe more.

You can find out about the type of a variable using [gettype()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php). It'll tell you that which variable does not contains an array. You can than change it to `array`.

*P.s: You're overriding your `$size` variable three times. Why is that?*

Answer (score -5):

In the doc it say :

Return Values
Returns the number of elements in value. When the parameter is neither an array nor an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned. There is one exception, if value is null, 0 will be returned.

It look like it a bug ?!?

Comment: That doesn't apply to PHP 8.