# critical error message displayed Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, azure

I have one Running Wordpress Site with Azure and i am migrating it to new site.
I imported .wpress file to new website yesterday and my website is now only displaying white screen with Internal server Error 500. I have enabled debug mode in wp-config.php and i got the following Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must
> be of type Countable|array, null given in
> /home/site/wwwroot/wp-content/plugins/sticky-side-buttons/ssb-main.php:217
> Stack trace: #0 /home/site/wwwroot/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308):
> ssb_main->ssb_icons_migration('') #1
> /home/site/wwwroot/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332):
> WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2
> /home/site/wwwroot/wp-includes/plugin.php(517):
> WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 /home/site/wwwroot/wp-settings.php(617):
> do_action('init') #4 /home/site/wwwroot/wp-config.php(138):
> require_once('/home/site/wwwr...') #5
> /home/site/wwwroot/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/site/wwwr...')
> #6 /home/site/wwwroot/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/site/wwwr...') #7
> /home/site/wwwroot/index.php(17): require('/home/site/wwwr...') #8
> {main} thrown in
> /home/site/wwwroot/wp-content/plugins/sticky-side-buttons/ssb-main.php
> on line 217

I am not sure what had Gone Wrong, I am really new in Wordpress.
this is my First website, can anyone please help?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: It looks like your migrating to a PHP 8 installation from  7.*.   You may want to disable or upgrade plugins that are not PHP 8 compatible. PHP 8 is a major release so downgrading your PHP installation to PHP 7 would probably be the easiest solution for now.

Comment: You could go through all the offending code and apply [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66671269/fatal-error-uncaught-typeerror-count-argument-1-var-must-be-of-type-cou), but that would be tedious and hacking core files and plugins is discouraged

Comment: Thank you For suggestion i Deactivated two Plugins that were not compatible with current version and it worked.